# window.history.back with hash not working properly on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a user reporting that clicking my "done button" in my app, which simply does a `window.history.back()` removes the entire hash, i.e. reducing `/mobile#/record/project` to only `/mobile`.

I cannot reproduce it and on all other devices:

- iPhone / Safari
- Android / Build in browser and Chrome
- IE 10 on desktop
- IE 11 on desktop
- Chrome/Safari/Firefox on desktop

...clicking the "done button" only removes the `/project` part of the hash. Taking the user back to where (s)he came from, i.e. `/mobile#/record`.

Anybody have experienced this with WinPhone before? Is my only solution to buy a WinPhone and try it my self?

Comment: I can confirm the behavior, I don't have a fix yet.

Comment: have you got any fix? I'm also struggling with this issue.